# Extract environment variables from actual usage in nodejs projects and generate a .env.sample file

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, sed, grep

The .env.sample files in the projects i work with are always outdated.  How would I write a one-liner to recursively search all files in a project and extract the used env variables to a .env.sample file.

The one-liner bash script should ideally match all the following formats

```
process.env.MY_VAR
process.env.MY-VAR
process.env["MY_VAR"]
process.env['MY_VAR']
process.env[MY_VAR] // MY_VAR here being a constant which holds the actual key value
```

Find the unique values and print to a sample .env file which could be plugged into a pre-commit hook or pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner which should work

```
grep -rhoP  "process\.env[\.\[](\"|\')?[A-Z0-9_\-]+(\"|\')?[\]]?" ./src \
| sed -r -n  's|^.*\.([[:upper:]0-9_-]+).*$|\1=|p' | sort --unique >  .env.sample
```

Breaking it down

1. `grep -rhoP  "process\.env[\.\[](\"|\')?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+(\"|\')?[\]]?" ./src`

   Grep modifiers

```
    -P, --perl-regexp
      Enables support for PCRE regexp
      Note: OpenBSD version of grep do not support PCRE expressions, GNU grep required on MacOS  

    -r recursive
      Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links 
      only if they are on the command line.

    -o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, on a separate output line.

    -h, --no-filename
      Suppress the prefixing of file names on output
```

2. The regex `process\.env[\.\[](\"|\')?[A-Z0-9_\-]+(\"|\')?[\]]?`

   - Matches the string literal `process.env`
   - `[\.\[]` matches the literal "." or "["
   - `(\"|\')?` matches single or double quotes optionally
   - `[A-Z0-9_\-]+` matches one or more the upper case, numbers , underscores and dashes
   - `(\"|\')?` matches single or double quotes optionally
   - `[\]]?` matches the literal "]" optionally
3. `sort --unique`  we only want distinct values and sorted alphabetically (makes diff comparison easier with consistent ordered list of keys )
4. `sed -r -n  's|^.*\.([[:upper:]0-9_]+).*$|\1=|p'`

   - shorter version of the previous regex matching all upper case characters , numbers, dashes after the literal "s." or starting with "."
   - inserts a "=" and prints the output silently

**Note** This is not a foolproof or comprehensive by any means . For example it does not match small case environment variables or plenty of other methods of access for example object deconstruction like `const { MY_VAR } = process.env`